# Retrieving no cookie from GET cookie

Tags: python, cookies, session-cookies, urllib2, urllib

When I would try to get the set cookie of an response instance I would get an None value when I use my actual login username and password.

```
import urllib2, urllib, cookielib 

jar = cookielib.CookieJar()                                                                                                                        
cookie = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar)                                                                                                                               
opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie) 

data = urllib.urlencode({'email':'user@hotmail.com','pass':'password','login':'Log+In'})
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.facebook.com/login.php')
response = opener.open(req, data)
response = opener.open(req, data) #I open it twice on purpose

if "Logout" in response.read():
    print("Logged In")
else:
   print("Not Logged In")

cookie_header = response.headers.get("Set-Cookie")
print(cookie_header)
```

I know how to set the cookie header, but the problem is a None value is being assigned to cookie_header when I use my actual credentials. How do I get the cookie?

Comment: The cookie would have been set on the **first** `opener.open()` connection. Where is `res` set?

Comment: Just use `requests` and its [sessions support](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) instead of hand wrangling this stuff.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, thats suppose to be response.

Answer (score 1):

By rearranging the code I was able to fix it up.

```
response = opener.open(req, data)
cookie_header = response.headers.get("Set-Cookie")
response = opener.open(req, data) #I open it twice on purpose
```

Because the cookie was set on the first open.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie will be set on the *first* response, you are testing the second instead. Facebook won't set *another* cookie here.

You could just get the cookie from the `CookieJar` object:

```
cookie = list(cookie.cookiejar)[0]
```

You'd have a much easier time of it if you used the [`request` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) instead:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

data = {'email':'user@hotmail.com','pass':'password','login':'Log+In'}
form = session.get('http://www.facebook.com/login.php')
response = session.post('http://www.facebook.com/login.php', data/data)
cookie_value = session.cookie['datr']
```